# PHP Static variable reloads after Page Load

Tags: php, forms, static, reload

This is a simplified version of what I want to accomplish:

In my script I want a static variable x to be incremented every time the submit button is pressed.

```
<?php
function IncX(){
   static $x = 0;
    $x++;
    echo $x;
}
?>

<body>
<form>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

But it **initializes to x=0** on every page reload after submit.

Comment: That is because the page is loaded every time the submit button is clicked... I think you have misunderstood what static variables do; they only retain their value for the one request. Clicking on the button sends multiple requests.

Comment: As said in the comment above, it's not how static variables work, look into `$_SESSION`

Comment: if then how to do so Olsen?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Using cookies would be a light-weight way of saving the value. Sessions are a little more heavy-duty, but they would also be a good solution.

Comment: if the page reloads for atleast 30 times.. which one will be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the variable afresh every time the page loads, so it's always going to be the same.

The solution is to store it in a session and then increment it there. Include a conditional to create the variable if it doesn't already exist.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['x'])) {
    $x = $_SESSION['x'];
  } else {
    $x = 0;
  }
  $x++;
  echo $x;
  $_SESSION['x'] = $x;
?>
```

Comment: even now the variable doesnot increment.. GeoFFAtkins

Comment: I am presuming that there was some reason for the increment to be handled within a function, and that you are calling the function somewhere on the page?

Comment: I have updated the answer to remove the function, this should resolve the matter. Make sure the `session_start()` is called before any headers are sent.

Answer (score 1):

Apache doesn't keep track of variables in php scrips between clicks, you would have to store it somewhere, be it the `$_SESSION` or a database.

Moreover, the [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) keyword doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It would work for successive calls of the function **in a single run of the script**, but not between clicks.

in any event, you can use the ternary operator to achieve this, would you happen to put it in the session. I've also added a check to make sure the variable is actually a viable count number:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['x'] = isset($_SESSION['x']) && is_int($_SESSION['x'])
    ? $_SESSION['x'] + 1
    : 1;
echo $_SESSION['x'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$x = 0;
    if (isset($_SESSION['x'])) {
      $x = $_SESSION['x'];
      $x++;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['x'] = $x;
    }
    // /$x++;
    echo $x;
    $_SESSION['x'] = $x;


?>
```

Comment: this is exactly the same as the other anser. what more did you add?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier When I added answer. Post was't edited and answer was wrong and by the time of edit you can see.